# How to init google oauth 2 onload?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-oauth

I have one issue in google oauth. I am using custom button and it take twice click to open the iframe. In first click it is going to init the id and in second click it open up the iframe. so how to resolve this twice clicking issue. I think just because using the custom button this all is happening.

**I am using following button**

```
<md-button class="md-raised google" id="customGoogleBtn" ng-click="vm.startApp()">
                <div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
                <span>
                    <md-icon md-font-icon="icon-google-plus" class="s16"></md-icon>
                    <span translate="LOGIN.WITH_GOOGLE">Log in with Google</span>
                </span>
                </div>
</md-button>
```

**And this the function in my controller which gets call after clicking the button**

```
function startApp(){
            gapi.load('auth2', function(){
            // Retrieve the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and set up the client.
                auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
                client_id: '997822731291-21sdd22ujqc78l1q2i2lmf5hfe5satj1.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
                fetch_basic_profile: 'true',
                // Request scopes in addition to 'profile' and 'email'
                //scope: 'additional_scope'
                });
                attachSignin(document.getElementById('customGoogleBtn'));
            });
        }

        function attachSignin(element) {
            auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
                function(googleUser) {
                    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
                    console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
                    console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
                    console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
                    console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
                    var pushData = [profile.getId(), profile.getName(), profile.getEmail()];
                    dataservice.addData(pushData);
                    $state.go('app.pages_auth_verify-mobile')
                }, 
                function(error) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
            });
        }
```